# Выдает ошибку Cannot resolve но код работает Spring Boot, HTML

Tags: html, spring-boot

Как пофиксить эту ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код работает отлично, все данные выводятся на сайт 0 ошибок при компиляции.

Код контролера

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@GetMapping("/adminPage")
public String adminPage(Model model){
    List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("userList",userList);
    return "adminPage";
}
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>playGame</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>playGame</name>
    <description>PlayGame</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Версия Intellij IDEA какая? Community или Ultimate?

Comment: Приведите первые строки шаблона с объявлением неймспейсов. (и на будущее: старайтесь всегда приводить весь код в текстовом виде. В виде скриншота код в сообществе не принимается. Если Вам важно показать подсветку синтаксиса, поведение IDE, иллюстрацию ошибок, то все равно лучше продублировать текстом и изображением. Не забывайте что участники сообщества скорее всего захотят использовать ваши примеры для помощи вам же. И заставлять всех набирать весь ваш код вручную не лучшая идея. В таком случае желающих помочь вам найдется немного.)

Comment: Если вкратце, то это не ошибка. В Вашем приложении ошибки нет и поэтому оно нормально запускается. Просто IDE не хватает информации для того чтобы связать ваш шаблон с методом контроллера и атрибуты контекста с используемыми переменными. Все на что это влияет - это отсутствие подсказок и автокомплита в шаблоне. В Community Edition эти возможности в принципе недоступны, поэтому если у Вас CE - вопрос можно закрывать. Для Ultimate Edition нужно больше информации, для того чтобы понять почему IDEA не может связать шаблон с контекстом.

Comment: Приложите также структуру проекта, настройки MVC, ViewResolver(если есть)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Версия Intellij IDEA Ultimate